# Wordpress Site Won't Load, Displaying the Error Message "There has been a critical error on this website" During Plugin Update

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, content-management-system

While updating plugins on my WordPress website, I noticed that they stopped updating so I refreshed the page and I got an error saying "There has been a critical error on this website". Now I can't access wp-admin.

What should I do to restore my website?

I cleared my browser's cache and tried renaming the plugin folder in my host's File Manager so far, the next step I am about to do is to see if it is a theme conflict causing the issue, and then increasing the php memory limit.

TIA

Comment: The actual error will probably be in the webserver logs.